# Installing 'requests' using easy_install

Tags: python

I'm trying to install 'requests module' using easy_install but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ sudo easy_install requests
Processing requests
error: Not a recognized archive type: requests
```

If I try with *pip*, I get the following error:

```
$ pip install requests
Unknown or unsupported command 'install'
```

Comment: sudo easy_install requests

Comment: try "pip install requests"

Comment: `install` is a valid pip command, so something is very wrong. What version of Ubuntu are you using? How did you install pip? What does `pip --version` say?

Comment: sudo apt-get install pip  and                                        pip v5.10.0

Comment: @Kummi_10: impossible. At this time, the latest version is 1.4.1 and 1.3.1 is shipped with the latest Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran the same commands as you, and didn't produce the same error.

```
$ sudo easy_install requests
Searching for requests
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/
Best match: requests 2.0.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/requests/requests-2.0.0.tar.gz#md5=856fc825c17483e25fd55db115028e3f
Processing requests-2.0.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-8vDXEw/requests-2.0.0/setup.cfg
Running requests-2.0.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-8vDXEw/requests-2.0.0/egg-dist-tmp-HTUm16
Adding requests 2.0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.0.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for requests
Finished processing dependencies for requests

$ pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.0.0-py2.7.egg
Cleaning up...
```

I will have to check what the log says, but as you see pip works just fine. You may need to reinstall pip:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove pip
sudo apt-get install pip
```

Comment: It installs just fine here, you're giving pip the wrong package name. It's requests. It's also a different error than the question, which have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @Timo thanks, for the missing `s` but either way it installs correctly.

Comment: I had to do "sudo pip install requests".